# get child by id in kivy and add new label to it

Tags: python, kivy

I am very new to python and kivy. I am recently working on a kivy server/client app that is based on the code from this site: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html

My goal is to create a server app that can receive messages from the client app, and will then transform one message from the client app to one label that can be touched/moved/scaled in a scatter widget individually. (i.e. if you have sent a 10 different messages from the client app you should be able to see 10 labels on the server screen that you can manipulate)

However with my limited knowledge in kivy and python, instead of adding new widgets, I can only achieve updating one widget. I just tried to use for loop to add new widgets, unfortunately I got stuck

Here is the version where it is working as it is only updating the label

class ServerApp(App):

```
def build(self):
    self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

    self.label = Button(text='Censoring process begin\nBeware of keyword "umbrella"\n ', color=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
    self.label.color = [0.9,0.2,0.2,1.0]

    self.upperscroll = Button(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'center_y': .5}, size_hint=(None, None))

    self.scatter = Scatter()

    self.displaybox = Label()
    self.displaybox.color = [0.4,0.9,0.4,1.0]

    reactor.listenTCP(8800, EchoFactory(self))
    reactor.listenTCP(8880, MultiEchoFactory(self))

    self.layout.add_widget(self.label)
    self.layout.add_widget(self.scatter)

    self.scatter.add_widget(self.displaybox)

    return self.layout

def handle_message(self, msg):

   if any(word in msg.lower() for word in wordlist):

       self.displaybox.color = [0.9,0.4,0.4,1.0]
       self.displaybox.text = "content blocked"
       self.label.text += "Alert! Sender posts %s \n" %msg


   else:
       self.label.text += "Safe - sender posts %s \n" %msg
       self.displaybox.color = [0.4,0.9,0.4,1.0]
       self.displaybox.text = "%s" % msg



   msg = msg


   return msg
```

this is the version where it does not work as it is trying to add new child widget

```
class ServerApp(App):


def build(self):
    i = 0
    self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

    self.label = Button(text='Censoring process begin\nBeware of keyword "umbrella"\n ', color=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
    self.label.color = [0.9,0.2,0.2,1.0]

    self.upperscroll = Button(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'center_y': .5}, size_hint=(None, None))

    self.scatter = Scatter(id="scatter" + str(i))

    self.displaybox = Label(id='displaybox' + str(i))
    self.displaybox.color = [0.4,0.9,0.4,1.0]

    reactor.listenTCP(8800, EchoFactory(self))
    reactor.listenTCP(8880, MultiEchoFactory(self))

    self.layout.add_widget(self.label)
    self.layout.add_widget(self.scatter)

    self.scatter.add_widget(self.displaybox)

    return self.layout

def handle_message(self, msg):

    for i in range(100):
       if any(word in msg.lower() for word in wordlist):

          self.layout.add_widget(self.scatter+str(i)(pos=(random(350),random(400))))
          self.scatter+str(i).add_widget(self.displaybox+str(i))

          **self.displaybox+i**.color = [0.9,0.4,0.4,1.0]
          **self.displaybox+i**.text = "content blocked"
            # this is where error occurs as python cannot identify the new label by adding "i"
          self.label.text += "Alert! Sender posts %s \n" %msg


    else:
         self.label.text += "Safe - sender posts %s \n" %msg
         self.scatter+i.add_widget(self.displaybox+i)
         self.displaybox+i.color = [0.4,0.9,0.4,1.0]
         self.displaybox+i.text = "%s" % msg

    i+=1

    msg = msg


    return msg
```

I wonder how could I fix this problem and add multiple scatter widgets with various labels once the (msg)message is sent from the client app?

Thank you so much

Comment: `It seems that the error is with the self.displaybox+i.color...`. Don't guess, please post the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the widget by id (provided if you use ids in your kv language code), use **ids**, like this:

```
...
scatter_id = 'scatter' + str(i) # form the id by string
scatter_widget = getattr(self.ids, scatter_id) # use getattr to access it 
displaybox_id = 'displaybox' + str(i)
displaybox_widget = getattr(self.ids, displaybox_id)
scatter_widget.add_widget(displaybox_widget)
...
```

Alternatively:

```
self.ids['scatter' + str(i)].add_widget(self.ids['displaybox' + str(i)])
...
```

Above are basically the same, it's more about readability and coding style.

You can read more about **Widget.ids** [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=ids#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids)

Hope this helps.